# Import Error : from django.core.handlers.wsgi import STATUS_CODE_TEXT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am super new with django and python and I'm having trouble getting the django rest framework integrated into my project.

I've got my model, serializer, and api in order, I think but when I attempt to run the server I get a string of errors:

(pyDev) C:\Users\pyDev\smrt>python manage.py run server
Performing system checks...

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000003FFD278
    >
    Traceback (most recent call last):
...
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 8, in <m
    odule>
        from rest_framework import views, mixins
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 14, in <mod
    ule>
        from rest_framework.response import Response
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 8, in <m
    odule>
        from django.core.handlers.wsgi import STATUS_CODE_TEXT
    ImportError: cannot import name STATUS_CODE_TEXT
```

Anyone have an idea of how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

- python: 2.7.14
- django: 1.11.6
- rest framework: 3.1.1
- virtualenv: 12.1.1

wpercy correctly points out that STATUS_CODE_TEXT has been removed from django, but I am not explicitly calling it from anywhere in my code. I guess that means it's somewhere in the rest_framework.generics code?

Is it possible that I'm using the rest_framework incorrectly and need to update my approach?

EDIT: I built a brand new project from scratch following the django rest framework tutorial, and I am able to return JSON objects just fine without the errors described here...

EDIT: This specifically appears to be the result of a call to include:

```
rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
```

EDIT:
Based on wpercy's advice I looked through the traceback more carefully and realized that the reference was pointing at my root python27\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py on line 8 as indicated above, I found:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import STATUS_CODE_TEXT
```

and then on line 81:

```
return STATUS_CODE_TEXT.get(self.status_code, '')
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
I found on the link that wpercy & commenter below posted

[Link to relevant ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24137). Jpadilla wrote:

In summary we should probably be able to do something like in response.py:

```
from django.utils.six.moves.http_client import responses
```

...

```
return responses.get(self.status_code, '')
```

I dropped in that suggestion which is a closed item on github:

[ticket for django-rest-framework Status code](https://github.com/maryokhin/django-rest-framework/commit/80c40fcf082d451b474647b6ce693bb5479783be)

and the server will now run. I'm not sure how I ended up with this older code? Perhaps I should uninstall and reinstall django-rest-framework to ensure that I have the latest, but dropping this code in did fix the issue.

EDIT:
Based on an answer I received from another question: ['Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects' but I'm already using Django 1.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837068/options-object-has-no-attribute-get-all-related-objects-but-im-already-usin?noredirect=1#comment80622172_46837068)
it turns out that I was using an old version of the rest framework with a new version of django. See Answer marked below

Comment: [That doesn't exist any more.](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2763)

Comment: I see that now, but I am not using wsgi.STATUS_CODE_TEXT anywhere in my code(on purpose)... where can I look for references to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because the `django-rest-framework` version you're using(v3.1.1) doesn't support Django version 1.11. [Support for Django v1.11 was not added in `django-rest-framework` until version 3.7](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.7-announcement/#django-20-support).

Upgrade `django-rest-framework` using pip: `pip install -U djangorestframework`

Comment: Thanks again @anupsabraham! This was driving me crazy!

Comment: Cool. Glad I am able to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

`django.core.handlers.wsgi.STATUS_CODE_TEXT` was removed in Django 1.9.

From the [Django 1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#miscellaneous):

> django.http.responses.REASON_PHRASES and django.core.handlers.wsgi.STATUS_CODE_TEXT have been removed. Use Python’s stdlib instead: http.client.responses for Python 3 and httplib.responses for Python 2.

Comment: Great thanks! ...again I am very new to this framework. How do I go about using stdlib instead of wsgi?  do I just modify the settings.py to point to httplib.responses?

Comment: I am not calling django.core.handlers.wsgi.STATUS_CODE_TEXT anywhere explicitly in my code, how can I find references to it in the project? Or am not on the right track?

Comment: @SumGuy the traceback will tell you which file the import statement is in. Please post the entire traceback.

Comment: Ah ok... I can't really follow the thread of the error messages, help interpreting them would be Great!  I edited the post to include the entire traceback.

Comment: I have updated my original question to include where I found the call to STATUS_CODE_TEXT.  But how do I go about fixing this? Thanks again.

Comment: I have marked another response as the answer, because while this response is correct, it does not address the root issue, and doesn't instruct one on how to fix it.  Thanks for your time though!