# 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects' but I'm already using Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I keep getting an
'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects' error. I've researched and people say it is often an issue with using an old version of django, but I'm using 1.11.6

when I navigate to the url: app/employees I get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Django Version:     1.11.6
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects'
```

other version numbers:

- python: 2.7.14
- rest framework: 3.1.1
- virtualenv: 12.1.1

app/model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('last_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
```

app/serializer:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

app/api.py:

```
class EmployeeApi(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

app/url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...    
url(r'^employees$', EmployeeApi.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Django 1.11 support is not added for django-rest-framework until version 3.7 I think. That could be your reason. Try upgrading django-rest-framework

Comment: @anupsabraham Ah ok! that might explain some other stuff that is going on for me. I'm VERY new with python and django, dhw do I upgrade django-rest-framework? using pip?

Comment: `pip install -U djangorestframework`

Comment: ok! That fixed that error! Now, I'm getting: Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '__all__' to the EmployeeSerializer serializer so I think I'm at least now working with the most version :)  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Django v1.11 support is not added for `django-rest-framework` until version 3.7](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.7-announcement/#django-20-support). Upgrading `django-rest-framework` should fix the issue.

To upgrade django-rest-framework, `pip install -U djangorestframework`

Comment: Yes! That did it. I think this is actually the answer to another question I posted, too:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819746/import-error-from-django-core-handlers-wsgi-import-status-code-text, could you post this answer there and I'll mark it as the answer as well?