# 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects'

Tags: python, django

Getting the above error while trying to log in. I have implemented [`django-users2`](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-users2) module. The following is the modules that I am using

```
Django Version: 2.1.5
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['myapp.apps.MyAdminConfig',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'category',
 'tag',
 'parttimejob',
 'myapp.core',
 'jobtype',
 'users',
 'django_extensions',
 'jobmessages',
 'search',
 'profiles',
 'employers',
 'employees',
 'jobtemplates',
 'tempus_dominus',
 'social_django',
 'background_task']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware']
```

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  398.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  61.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  141.         if form.is_valid():

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  382.         self._clean_form()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  409.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  196.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  73.             user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  16.             user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in get_by_natural_key
  44.         return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/users/managers.py" in get_queryset
  55.         return InheritanceQuerySet(self.model).select_subclasses()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/model_utils/managers.py" in select_subclasses
  20.             self.model, levels=levels)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/model_utils/managers.py" in _get_subclasses_recurse
  103.             rel for rel in model._meta.get_all_related_objects()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects'
```

I have referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837068/options-object-has-no-attribute-get-all-related-objects-but-im-already-usin) and upgraded django, djangorestframework, but none of them seem to work. I am new to django. Please ask for any more information that I could provide. Please Guide me in resolving the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course upgrading DRF doesn't solve your issue since the issue isn't with DRF - it's in the InheritanceManager code , which comes from django-models-utils and [is a dependance of django-users-2](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-users2#features). And FWIW, [the issue has been fixed 2 years ago](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/pull/207), so your django-models-utils version is probably quite outdated.

Note that all you had to do to debug this by yourself was to 1/ read the traceback to find out where the issue happens, 2/ go to the gitlab of the project, 3/ search the error message (or part of it - I searched for "get_all_related_objects") - in the issues tracker (searching closed issues too), 4/ read the issue description, status and resolution.

Comment: Thank you so much.....that resolved the issue...you've been of great help!